# LUB of List of Invariant Class's Instances

Tags: scala

Given a class with a `covariant` type parameter:

```
scala> class G[+A]
defined class G
```

The following list shows a Least Upper Bound of `List[G[Any]]`.

```
scala> List(new G[Int], new G[String])
res1: List[G[Any]] = List(G@5aa360ea, G@6548bb7d)
```

Then, given a class with an `invariant` type parameter:

```
scala> class F[A]
defined class F
```

I see a Least Upper Bound (LUB) of `List[F[_ >: String with Int]]`.

```
scala> List(new F[Int], new F[String])
res0: List[F[_ >: String with Int]] = List(F@6c4980d3, F@327bcebd)
```

A simpler example shows a LUB of `List[Any]`:

```
scala> List( (42 : Int), "foobar" )
res2: List[Any] = List(42, foobar)
```

Please explain the LUB of the `List` of `F`'s.

Answer (score 2):

`G` is *covariant* over its type parameter `A`. This means that given any types `A` and `B`, if `A` is a *sub-type* of `G`, then `G[A]` is a *sub-type* of `G[B]`. Let's write this in short-hand to using `A <:< B` to denote that `A` is a *sub-type* of `B`, then `G[A] <:< G[B]`.

This means that when we have a `List(new G[Int], new G[String])`, the compiler is allowed to infer it as a `List[Any]`, because `List[G[Int]] <:< List[G[Any]]` and `List[G[String]] <:< List[G[Any]]` (since `List` is *also covariant* over its type parameter).

You probably already know that, but it's worth explaining for those that don't yet.

`F` is *invariant* over its type parameter `A`, so we cannot make the same deductions. Okay, so then what is the type of `List(new F[Int], new F[String])` ? Because `F` is *invariant*, we cannot say that `F[Int] <:< F[Any]` or that `F[String] <:< F[Any]` (because it's not true!). So it's not a `List[F[Any]].`

So what can the compiler infer? It's only real choice is some existential type, because it cannot be `Any`, or `String with Int`, or anything else without breaking covariance. Since it is looking for the *least upper-bound*, it infers an existential type that is bounded below by the compound of the contained types (in `F`). That is, `_ >: String with Int` is *some nameless type* that has a *lower-bound* of `String with Int`.

Or, in other words, we know we have a `List` of `F`s, but we *don't know* what type is contained in each of them. Only that any given `F` in the `List` is an `F[Int]`, or a `F[String]`, but that's it.